# SQL query to exclude one to many that have a specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL, I'd like to list all users that don't have the document "liaison". It could means Users that does not have any document at all, or users that have documents, but not "liaison" in these ones.

How can I do using MySQL Query ? I can't make it work!

Here's the (simple) model

```
Users (id, name)
Documents (id, user_id, name, path)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NOT EXISTS` is a workable solution. As an alternative, sometimes, with large sets, an "anti JOIN" operation can give better performance:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM Users u
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT d.user_id
          FROM Documents d
         WHERE d.name = 'liaison'
       ) l
    ON l.user_id = u.id
 WHERE l.user_id IS NULL
```

The inline view aliased as `l` returns us a list of user_id that have document named 'liaison'; that result set gets outer joined to the Users table, and then we exclude any rows where we found a match (the test of l.user_id IS NULL).

This returns a resultset equivalent to your query with the `NOT EXISTS` predicate.

Another alternative is to use a query with a `NOT IN` predicate. Note that we need to guarantee that the subquery does not return a NULL, so the general approach is to include an IS NOT NULL predicate on the column being returned by the subquery.

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM Users u
 WHERE u.id NOT IN 
       ( SELECT d.user_id 
           FROM Documents d
          WHERE d.user_id IS NOT NULL
            AND d.name = 'liaison'
       )
```

I'd write the `NOT EXISTS` query like this:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM Users u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM Documents d
          WHERE d.name = 'liaison'
            AND d.user_id = u.id
       )
```

My personal preference is to use a literal 1 in the SELECT list of that correlated subquery; it reminds me that the query is just looking for the existence of 1 row.)

Again, I usually find that the "anti-join" pattern gives the best performance with large sets. (You'd need to look at the EXPLAIN output for each statement, and measure the performance of each to determine which will work best in your situation.)

Answer (score 2):

The correct query you are looking for is:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Users 
WHERE 
    id NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            user_id 
        FROM 
            Documents 
        WHERE 
            name = "liaison"
    )
```

This will achieve the exact result you are looking for. If a specific user has no documents, it will be listed. If it has many documents, and one of those is 'liaison', it won't be listed.

If you want to search for 'liaison' in your document's name, replace `name = "liaison"` for `name LIKE "%liaison%"`.

It basically says: Select all users such as there are no documents with name "liaison" pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Users where not exists (select id from Documents where Users.id = Documents.id and Documents.name = 'liaison')
```

Comment: He wants to avoid documents containing "liaison", and allow users without documents...

Comment: I came up with a close idea that seems to be working : `SELECT *
FROM users u WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_documents WHERE name = 'LIAISON')
ORDER BY c.lastname, c.firstname`

Comment: @CyrilN. : Where do this column come from ? You didn't mention any 'type' column. But this seems to work, yes :)

Comment: oh right.  Well, you could just change that to select * from users where not exists...that would be much more efficient

Comment: my "type" is the "name" I gave here (I simplified the models).

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally came up with this solution that seems to work good :

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_documents WHERE name = 'LIAISON') ORDER BY c.lastname, c.firstname
```

Comment: Beware of the expression in the SELECT list of the subquery returning a NULL value. If a NULL is returned, then *no rows* in the outer query will be returned. Because no rows will satisfy the predicate **`expr NOT IN (...,NULL,...)`**.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users left join Documents
     on users.id = Documents.user_id
        and documents.name='LIAISON'
WHERE documents.user_id is null
```

Comment: No, it will include users that have documents including "liaison"

Comment: @CyrilN. it won't, there's a double condition on the join clause, i'm trying to join users with documents with the name "liaison", if the join doesn't succeed user_id will be null

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u LEFT JOIN documents d ON d.user_id = u.id
WHERE d.id IS NULL OR d.name NOT LIKE '%liaison%'
```

Remove percent signs if "liaison" is the exact name of the document.

Comment: I tried, and it still returns users that have this document (because it exclude this document, but if the user has 2 documents, Liaison and an other, he will be listed)

Comment: Aw, my bad. You're right, and I'm dumb :) Should have tested it.